# Frame identification

Tags: frames

[image][image]
[image]

Any idea of the maker of this carbon frame, if more photos needed just let me know

Comment: To be frank, it looks handmade — and not in a good way. I’m not sure i would ride it myself.

Comment: Threadless headset, down tube shifters, lugged carbon. Someone really true to get the weight down in the nineties. But then a square taper bottom bracket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a Specialized Epic frame.
Hate to post an [ebay link but they had good](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Specialized-Epic-Comp-Carbon-Road-Bike-Frame-Vintage-80s-58cm-L-Damaged-Charity/253205449001?hash=item3af4388929:g:438AAOSw7XNcyzMW) pictures. And when I say "good" I mean that there were many detailed shots. The pictures are of a pretty frightening frame.

[image]

Comment: Hmm strikingly similar I think you found it thanks!